# HttpClient, server committed a protocol violation Section=ResponseHeader Detail=CR must be followed by LF

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I am using the HttpClient to communicate with a GoPro Camera over WiFi, but I am getting the following error. "**The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseHeader Detail=CR must be followed by LF**" Although I have notified them, I cannot change GoPro's web server, so I need to resolve/ignore this on the client side. When i make this call, using Fiddler as a proxy, Fiddler corrects the issue and my app runs as expected. But without fiddler i get the protocol violation message.

From the searching i have done this can be resolved by adding `<httpWebRequest useUnsafeHeaderParsing = "true"/>` (see [HttpWebRequestElement.UseUnsafeHeaderParsing Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.configuration.httpwebrequestelement.useunsafeheaderparsing.aspx)), but this is a Windows 8 store app and there is no configuration file.

One option is to write a custom handler and inject it into the HttpClient ctor, but I am not sure where to start with my own custom handler and it seems like a big effort for something that should be built in.

Is there a simple solution?

Comment: I am facing a similar problem with a Windows Phone app using Mashape API (it changed near the end of June). It's really unfortunate Microsoft refuses to allow the Phone/Store apps to be a bit more lenient.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it myself but maybe you can change the element by code like this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ff098248-551c-4da9-8ba5-358a9f8ccc57/how-do-i-enable-useunsafeheaderparsing-from-code-net-20

Comment: Looked at that option already, but this is a windows store app and System.Net.Configuration does not exist :-(

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately writing your own handler doesn't work either because the system's `HttpClientHandler` gets called before your custom one when the response is returned.

For Windows Store apps, you can use `MessageWebSocket`: I attempted something similar for Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight using `StreamSocket`; see [How can I accept "unsafe" HTTP response headers in a Windows Phone/Store app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25209693/how-can-i-accept-unsafe-headers-in-a-windows-phone-store-app)